# chrome.offscreen reason "WORKERS" does not work

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

```
chrome.offscreen.createDocument({
  url: chrome.runtime.getURL('off_screen.html'),
  reasons: ['WORKERS'],
  justification: 'reason for needing the document',
});
```

When I try to create offscreen document for my chrome extension, it throws an error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Error in invocation of 
offscreen.createDocument(offscreen.CreateParameters parameters, function callback): 
Error at parameter 'parameters': 
Error at property 'reasons': 
Error at index 1: Value must be one of 
AUDIO_PLAYBACK, BLOBS, CLIPBOARD, DISPLAY_MEDIA, DOM_PARSER, DOM_SCRAPING, 
IFRAME_SCRIPTING, TESTING, USER_MEDIA, WEB_RTC.
```

In documentation "**WORKERS**" are clearly there

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/offscreen/#type-Reason

Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it if possible?

Comment: See [what's new](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/whatsnew/): it was added in Chrome 113.

Comment: Thank you very much. I see. BTW, I can not create a worker inside my v3 extension background service worker and as a last resort I tried to create an example worker in offscreen.html with a WORKERS reason but still received ```Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to construct 'Worker': Script at 'chrome-extension://ihhbpigkocmjgmpgdhdhjohcbmejchcb/worker.js' cannot be accessed from origin 'null'.``` Is it possible to create a worker in chrome extension or not, please?

Comment: Service worker [can't created nested workers yet](https://crbug.com/1219164). Simply specify a different offscreen reason.

Comment: No, I mean even if I create offscreen document, Chrome does not allow me to create a worker there. I tried to create worker in popup.html and the same error about origin occurs.

Comment: It's certainly possible both in the offscreen document and in the popup. Without seeing [MCVE](/help/mcve) I guess you open popup.html as `file://` or as `localhost`. Do it properly by pressing the extension icon in the toolbar or by manually assembling the correct chrome-extension:// URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [what's new](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/whatsnew/): WORKERS was added in Chrome 113.

In older versions of Chrome you can use a fallback reason like this:

```
  reasons: [chrome.offscreen.Reason.WORKERS || chrome.offscreen.Reason.IFRAME_SCRIPTING],
```